# Copy large files from remote(Windows 8) to local (windows 8) and vice versa using python

Tags: python

How to Copy large files from remote(Windows 8) to local (windows 8)  and vice versa using python??
I want to copy the zip files of 5gb and 10gb from remote to local and vice versa using python in single script?

Answer (score 0):

You can use boto library.The boto library for Python supports multipart upload, and the latest boto software includes an "s3multiput" command line tool that takes care of the complexities for you and even parallelizes part uploads.Go through following links

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadingObjects.html

http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/11/amazon-s3-multipart-upload.html